# How to implement "__iadd__()" for an immutable type?

Tags: python, immutability, augmented-assignment

I would like to subclass an immutable type or implement one of my own which behaves like an `int` does as shown in the following console session:

```
>>> i=42
>>> id(i)
10021708
>>> i.__iadd__(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__iadd__'
>>> i += 1
>>> i
43
>>> id(i)
10021696
```

Not surprisingly, `int` objects have no `__iadd__()` method, yet applying `+=` to one doesn't result in an error, instead it apparently creates a new `int` and also somehow magically reassigns it to the name given in the augmented assignment statement.

Is it possible to create a user-defined class or subclass of a built-in immutable one that does this, and if so, how?

Comment: Is there a reason you want `__iadd__` instead of `__add__`?

Comment: @Michael Mauderer: Yes, I want to know how to emulate the behavior of `int` and other immutable types in this regard.

Comment: Unless you're doing something hacky and/or unconventional with the operators (which is of course permitted), the statement `i += j` should be equivalent to `i = i + j` for immutable types. Thus one of the following presumably applies if you've implemented `__iadd__` for an immutable type: either you've also implemented `__add__` identically, introducing duplicate code and a maintenance trap, or you've not implemented `__add__` at all, needlessly losing the ability to also use the `+` operator which you could have got for free just by implementing `__add__` instead of `__iadd__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of `__iadd__()` is used. You don't need to return the object that's being added to; you can create a new one and return that instead. In fact, if the object is immutable, you *have* to.

```
import os.path

class Path(str):
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        return Path(os.path.join(str(self), str(other)))

path = Path("C:\\")
path += "windows"

print path
```

Comment: Good answer and example...but @phihag beat you, timing-wise.

Comment: Our answers are distinctly different; I'm fine with you choosing his (it's fine) but I just wanted to show that `__iadd__()` will do what you expect. You might want to make regular addition and in-place addition do something totally different, and in that case you'll need to implement both.

Comment: Ahhh, so `__iadd__()` _can_ return a value -- which is surprising if you think about it -- and you can have both, even on an immutable (sub)class. Subtle but excellent points, guess I'll have to reconsider my choice.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer. Note that it can be very dangerous and misleading to implement `__iadd__` and `__add__` differently. For example, `path = path + "System"` sets path to `C:\WindowsSystem`. So a real-world implementation of Path should define `__add__` and either implement it or raise an exception.

Comment: Yes, you have to be very careful. Note that for some built-in types, however, `__add__` and `__iadd__` are in fact implemented very differently. One example is lists, where `+` produces a new list and `+=` mutates an existing one. If you have multiple references to the list, which one you use can be very important!

Comment: This is a bad idea. The language docs [Emulating numeric types](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) section explicitly says "These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying self)". While you _can_ get away with misusing `__iadd__` this way, you shouldn't. Just leave it out, and the interpreter will call `__add__` instead.

Comment: -1 for the reason given by abarnert. While this answer is technically correct, it gives the impression of advising implementing `__iadd__` for immutable types (and certainly doesn't warn against doing so), which is pointless, contrary to the documentation, and inconsistent with how Python's built-in immutable types are implemented.

Comment: Y'all's definition of "should" is contrary to the dictionary. There is no reason whatsoever not to implement `__iadd__` for immutable types and no reason to "warn" against doing so. It's not as if it won't work perfectly fine. *This is why the return value is used, people.* If `__iadd__` was meant to be used only for mutable types then it wouldn't need the return value. Actually, I find the fact that `+` and `+=` do totally different things with mutable types the confusing thing! Now, a good argument against `__iadd__` is that it's generally redundant if you've implemented `__add__`.

Comment: Well, my dictionaries say "should" means "must". However the cited docs don't say `__ixxx__` methods shouldn't be implemented for immutable types. What they do say is "These methods **should** attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying _self_) and return the result (which could be, **but does not have to be**, _self_)" (my emboldening). Since in-place operations are, by definition, impossible on immutable types, skipping any attempt to do so and just returning a new value sounds like a perfectly acceptable way of emulating immutable built-ins in respect to these kinds of operations.

Comment: in py3, there is `pathlib.Path`

Answer (score 16):

Simply don't implement `__iadd__`, but only `__add__`:

```
>>> class X(object):
...     def __add__(self, o):
...             return "added"
>>> x = X()
>>> x += 2
>>> x
'added'
```

If there's no `x.__iadd__`, Python simply calculates `x += y` as `x = x + y` [<sup>doc</sup>](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__).

Comment: Yes, that does work and do the reassignment. Thanks. So the appears to be no way to differentiate between the two (even though that's likely fine in almost all cases).

Comment: This is almost certainly the answer you actually want. Immutable objects should not implement the `__ifoo__` methods.

Answer (score 3):

When it sees `i += 1`, Python will try to call `__iadd__`. If that fails, it'll try to call `__add__`.

In both cases, the result of the call will be bound to the name, i.e. it'll attempt `i = i.__iadd__(1)` and then `i = i.__add__(1)`.

Comment: "If that fails" is somewhat imprecise. If the `__iadd__` does exist, it is called, and errors raised by it are reraised.

Comment: @phihag To be even more pedantic, I'll just note that `__add__` will also be called if `__iadd__` returns `NotImplemented`. I'm not sure if this is ever useful in practice; perhaps it could be if you wanted to implement an immutable version of a class as a subclass of the mutable version, and override the `__iadd__` method to make `+=` fall back on `__add__`. I suppose you might also use this if you had a class for which in-place modification was reasonable when adding certain types, but not when adding some other types to it, and in the latter case falling back on `__add__` was desirable.

Answer (score -1):

```
class aug_int:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.value += other
        return self

>>> i = aug_int(34)
>>> i
<__main__.aug_int instance at 0x02368E68>
>>> i.value
34
>>> i += 55
>>> i
<__main__.aug_int instance at 0x02368E68>
>>> i.value
89
>>>
```

Comment: This doesn't define a class of immutable objects.