# what is the difference between two assignment operator in python?

Tags: python

```
In [38]: d = set(range(3))

In [39]: d
Out[39]: set([0, 1, 2])

In [40]: for i in d:
    d  -= set([2])
   ....:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/gridlex/workspace/HomeBackSites/nava_scripts/<ipython-input-40-b79926ab34ec> in <module>()
----> 1 for i in d:
      2     d  -= set([2])
      3 

RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration
```

what is the difference between these two assignments in python?

1.**d -= set([2])**

2 **d = d - set([2])**

```
In [41]: d = set(range(3))

In [42]: for i in d:
    d = d - set([2])
   ....:     

In [43]: d
Out[43]: set([0, 1])
```

Comment: Damn you search and operators. Surely this is a duplicate.

Comment: Was thinking the same thing.

Comment: Searching for `__iadd__`, `__isub__`, etc. should be easier. But the first thing I found, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836570/how-to-implement-iadd-for-immutable-type), is about how to implement +=, not what it does, and its accepted answer is misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With immutable types like integers, `a -= b` is the same thing as `a = a - b`: It creates a new value, `a - b`, and re-binds the name `a` to refer to that new value instead of the old one.

But with mutable types like sets, `a -= b` changes the value that `a` is pointing to in-place. (It also re-binds `a` to the same value it's already referring to, but that's not important.)

The best way to see this is by looking at the object's identity:

```
>>> s1 = set(range(3))
>>> s2 = s1
>>> s1, id(s1), s2, id(s2)
({0, 1, 2}, 4303749432, {0, 1, 2}, 4303749432)
>>> s1 -= {1}
>>> s1, id(s1), s2, id(s2)
({0, 2}, 4303749432, {0, 2}, 4303749432)
>>> s1 = s1 - {2}
>>> s1, id(s1), s2, id(s2)
({0}, 4303749664, {0, 2}, 4303749432)
```

Notice that the `-=` leaves `s1` still referring to the same set as `s2`, and changes that set; the `-` leaves `s1` referring to a brand-new set with a different `id`, and doesn't affect `s2`.

---

Under the covers, `a = a - b` is roughly* equivalent to `a = a.__sub__(b)`, while `a -= b` is equivalent to `a = a.__isub__(b)`. Except that if there is no `__isub__` method, `a -= b` just uses `__sub__` instead.

The fact that `__isub__` changes the value, while `__sub__` returns a new value, isn't really enforced by the language, but it's something that's true of all built-in and stdlib types, and expected to be true of any custom types. It's described in [Emulating numeric types](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) in the docs:

> These [`__ifoo__`] methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying *self*) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, *self*). If a specific method is not defined, the augmented assignment falls back to the normal methods. For instance, to execute the statement `x += y`, where *x* is an instance of a class that has an `__iadd__()` method, `x.__iadd__(y)` is called. If *x* is an instance of a class that does not define a `__iadd__()` method, `x.__add__(y)` and `y.__radd__(x)` are considered, as with the evaluation of `x + y`.

---

* It's not *exactly* equivalent because of (a) `__rsub__`, (b) types implemented in C (like `set`), and (c) rules for looking up certain special methods being different from normal methods.